# native php function to highlight javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, function, syntax-highlighting

Is there any native PHP function as [highlight_string();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) but for javascript ?

Or, if not, is there any PHP function (homemade) to do it?

EDIT: I want to use PHP function to COLORIZE javascript

Comment: You mean a native function to highlight javascript I presume? Otherwise you answered your own question ;)

Comment: yes, you're right. I know how to colorize php by php but I want to know, how to colorize javascript with php :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had great success with [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/). Easy to use and integrate in your app and it supports a **lot** of languages.

Comment: that looks good, I will try it. However, I looking for single-function right now

Comment: There's no such thing as a single function to do that. Highlighting is too complex to capture in a single function and be understandable. If you do find a single function then it will be one unwieldy monster! PHP's `highlight_string()` only *looks* like a single function because the rest is hidden inside PHP itself.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want a Syntax Highligher written in PHP. This one (Geshi) has worked for me in the past:

http://qbnz.com/highlighter/

Comment: it's great tool as I seen on demo, but I'm searching for single-function right now :) I'll give you +1 tho

Comment: `function highlight($string, $language) { include_once 'geshi.php'; $geshi = new GeSHi($string, $language); return $geshi->parse_code();}` :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the PHP function highlight_string() is a native PHP function for PHP.

Comment: I believe the OP means for javascript..check the title

Comment: Oho, well now that's a different question... :)

Comment: I want to find PHP function to be able to highlight javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

No.

But there are a lot of javascript libraries that do syntax-highlight on several languages,
from bash-scripting to php and javascript.

eg, like [snippet](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/) (JQuery) or [jQuery.Syntax](http://www.oriontransfer.co.nz/projects/jquery-syntax/index.en) (my favorite)

Answer (score 1):

Over [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) you can find an excellent library which enables syntax highlighting in a large amount of languages using javascripts and a css class.

There is no native php function to do this, so either you have to use existing libraries or you have to write something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way - you can use also PHP function "highlight_string" with a little trick 
(capture function output and remove leading/trailing PHP tags):

```
$source = '... some javascript ...';

// option 1 - pure JS code
$htmlJs = highlight_string('<?php '.$source.' ?>', true);
$htmlJs = str_replace(array('&lt;?php&nbsp;', '&nbsp;?&gt;'), array('', ''), $htmlJs);

// option 2 - when mixing up with PHP code inside of JS script
$htmlJs = highlight_string('START<?php '.$source.' ?>END', true);
$htmlJs = str_replace(array('START<span style="color: #0000BB">&lt;?php&nbsp;</span>', '&nbsp;?&gt;END'), array('', ''), $htmlJs);
// check PHP INI setting for "highlight.keyword" (#0000BB) - http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.syntax-highlighting
```

Answer (score 1):

No native function, but rather than using a full stack library just to highlight some javascript you can use this single function :

```
function format_javascript($data, $options = false, $c_string = "#DD0000", $c_comment = "#FF8000", $c_keyword = "#007700", $c_default = "#0000BB", $c_html = "#0000BB", $flush_on_closing_brace = false)
{

    if (is_array($options)) { // check for alternative usage
        extract($options, EXTR_OVERWRITE); // extract the variables from the array if so
    } else {
        $advanced_optimizations = $options; // otherwise carry on as normal
    }
    @ini_set('highlight.string', $c_string); // Set each colour for each part of the syntax
    @ini_set('highlight.comment', $c_comment); // Suppression has to happen as some hosts deny access to ini_set and there is no way of detecting this
    @ini_set('highlight.keyword', $c_keyword);
    @ini_set('highlight.default', $c_default);
    @ini_set('highlight.html', $c_html);

    if ($advanced_optimizations) { // if the function has been allowed to perform potential (although unlikely) code-destroying or erroneous edits
        $data = preg_replace('/([$a-zA-z09]+) = \((.+)\) \? ([^]*)([ ]+)?\:([ ]+)?([^=\;]*)/', 'if ($2) {' . "\n" . ' $1 = $3; }' . "\n" . 'else {' . "\n" . ' $1 = $5; ' . "\n" . '}', $data); // expand all BASIC ternary statements into full if/elses
    }

    $data = str_replace(array(') { ', ' }', ";", "\r\n"), array(") {\n", "\n}", ";\n", "\n"), $data); // Newlinefy all braces and change Windows linebreaks to Linux (much nicer!)
    $data = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $data); // Regex identifies all extra empty lines produced by the str_replace above. It is quicker to do it like this than deal with a more complicated regular expression above.
    $data = str_replace("<?php", "<script>", highlight_string("<?php \n" . $data . "\n?>", true));

    $data = explode("\n", str_replace(array("<br />"), array("\n"), $data));

# experimental tab level highlighting
    $tab = 0;
    $output = '';

    foreach ($data as $line) {
        $lineecho = $line;
        if (substr_count($line, "\t") != $tab) {
            $lineecho = str_replace("\t", "", trim($lineecho));
            $lineecho = str_repeat("\t", $tab) . $lineecho;
        }
        $tab = $tab + substr_count($line, "{") - substr_count($line, "}");
        if ($flush_on_closing_brace && trim($line) == "}") {
            $output .= '}';
        } else {
            $output .= str_replace(array("{}", "[]"), array("<span style='color:" . $c_string . "!important;'>{}</span>", "<span style='color:" . $c_string . " !important;'>[]</span>"), $lineecho . "\n"); // Main JS specific thing that is not matched in the PHP parser
        }

    }

    $output = str_replace(array('?php', '?&gt;'), array('script type="text/javascript">', '&lt;/script&gt;'), $output); // Add nice and friendly <script> tags around highlighted text

    return '<pre id="code_highlighted">' . $output . "</pre>";
}
```

Usage :

```
echo format_javascript('console.log("Here is some highlighted JS code using a single function !");') ;
```

Credit : 
http://css-tricks.com/highlight-code-with-php/ 
Demo : 
http://css-tricks.com/examples/HighlightJavaScript/

Answer (score 0):

Well nice info here . Here is another nice one : http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: I'm looking for PHP function!